# Put current changes in a new Git branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I've been editing some modules on the master branch but I haven't committed them. I'm now thinking that these changes should really be on an experimental branch and not the master branch.

How can I get these edits into an experimental branch? Copy them to some temp location, create the branch, and then copy them back in?

And how do I configure things so that when I do a git push from the new experimental branch it will it go into a branch of the same name in my GitHub repo?

Comment: I think this is another question, according to the question title

Answer (score 440, accepted):

You can simply check out a new branch, and then commit:

```
git checkout -b my_new_branch
git commit
```

Checking out the new branch will not discard your changes.

Comment: @antoine-pelisse what would happen if I did not include the `-b` flag and/or if I switched to an existing branch where I wanted to continue working with those changes?

Comment: Changes are not there when you go back and checkout "master" -- nice -- exactly what I would want.

Comment: @WebUser - `git checkout my-branch` refuses to do the checkout if it would overwrite uncommitted changes. To start working with your existing changes on a different branch, you can do `git stash`, then `git checkout my-branch` and then either `git stash pop` (removes the stash if it applies without conflicts) or `git stash apply` (does not remove the stash even if it applies without conflicts).

Comment: To push the branch to upstream, you need to do git push --set-upstream origin <my_new-branch>

Comment: I think it would be great to add the comment from @sachin to the answer (i.e. how to push the branch upstream afterwords)