# Moving uncommitted changes to a new branch: git: stash vs checkout

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-stash

I've done some changes to my code in `branch1`, but now I need to move those changes to another branch.  Graphically, I have:

```
master
  |___develop
         |___branch1
```

and I need to move all the **uncommitted changes and untracked files** to a new branch `branch2` (which does not exist):

```
master
  |___develop
         |___branch1
         |___branch2
```

after which I'll just delete `branch1` since all its changes are already pushed, and be left with all the uncommitted changes and untracked files in `branch2`:

```
master
  |___develop
         |___branch2
```

There are quite a few of similar questions in SO but I'm still not sure how I should proceed in my case. Some say to use `git stash` ([How do I merge my local uncommitted changes into another Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/556923/1391441), [moving changed files to another branch for check-in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7217894/1391441)) which in my case I guess would be:

```
git stash -u
git checkout develop
git checkout -b branch2
git stash pop
```

but other answers ([Put current changes in a new Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4746672/1391441), [Moving uncommitted changes to a new branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13687334/1391441)) say to simply use `checkout` as:

```
git checkout -b branch2
```

but I'm not sure if this will carry my untracked files too. There's a newer answer that recommends using `switch` ([Move existing, uncommitted work to a new branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1394797/1391441)), but my `git` version  2.17.1 does not have this command.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your piece of commands describing the first method you mentioned (git stash -u etc.) will work. Because -u flag is actually --include-untracked, which is what you need.

Comment: `switch` doesn't really do anything different than `checkout`; rather, it's a more accurate description of a subset of `checkout`'s functionality. `restore` is the other new command that will do whatever `checkout` does that `switch` doesn't. Between `switch` and `restore`, there shouldn't be any need to use `checkout`, and it can be retired.

Comment: This question asks for clarification, then it accept the first answer, one that doesn't even give much more details on the difference between these commands. More answers will come, eventually bringing us back to the same confusion that led to this very question, basically making this question a duplicate of one of the question it mentions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `stash` is safer, as it avoids any problems that might pop up with switching branches with a dirty working directory. `stash` even has a subcommand for directly creating a branch from a stash.

```
git stash -u
git checkout develop
git stash branch branch2
```

Comment: `git stash branch` creates the new branch using the stash's parent commit, which means your `git checkout develop` step here has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do

```
git checkout -b branch2
```

this will carry along all your changes. After all creating the branch is not much more than "labelling" the current commit with the name `branch2`.

Comment: Will this carry the untracked files too? What is the difference with `stash` that involves more steps?

Comment: Yes it will carry untracked files. The difference to the solution involving `stash` is what @chepner mentions in his answer: problems that might pop up with switching branches with a dirty working directory.

Comment: @michid what exactly are the problems that “might pop up”?